# Angularjs directive - isolated scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive `myToolbar` that should dynamically create and append `toolbarItems`, triggered by an event. Each `toolbarItem` is passed different data.

Please, check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZaUY/49/):

The output is `"baz baz baz"`  but it should be `"foo bar baz"`.

Each `toolbarItem` has a isolated scope, but the `toolbarData` of all `toolbarItems` is overwritten by the last one.

What did I wrong?

I have a solution ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/u3228/4/)). But this can't be the way to go in angular.

I serialized the the `toolbarData` and wrote it to the `toolbarItem` markup.

Does someone know a clean solution?

Comment: Why broadcast? Why element.append? honestly, have you read anything about angular yet? Because this can be done waaaay simpler

Comment: In my application I get the toolbarData via WebSockets. I have to build a toolbar with the toolbarData programmatically when it received. It's my first Angular Project. How can i make it better?

Comment: I would definitely use ng-repeat and bind an array on the scope - and you can then push or remove items from array and it will be propagated into the view right away

Comment: And it doesn't matter how the data is loaded, the $broadcast can be changed to bind a scope variable to myToolbar directive and it will update on the fly as you need

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have refactored my app. Now I use ng-repeat to create the toolbarItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recompiling all the `toolbar-items` on each call:

- You should get a reference to the newly created element.
- You should only compile once each `toolbar-item`

#### Solution:

Here is a working fork: http://jsfiddle.net/q8bUK/

```
scope.$on('addToolbarItem', function (e, toolbarData) {
    var newElm = angular.element('<toolbar-item>a</toolbar-item>');
    element.append(newElm);
    newElm.attr("toolbarData", JSON.stringify(toolbarData));                
    $compile(newElm)(scope);
});
```